# Есть ли здесь прилагательные?

Tags: прилагательные

> Люди часто сажают деревья около своих домов. Деревья защищают их от ветра, очищают воздух от пыли. Сажают деревья и вдоль дороги. Они хорошо затеняют ее. Часто их высаживают на границах полей. Деревья не дают ветрам уносить почву.

Требуется указать в этом тексте существительные, прилагательные и глаголы, но я не нахожу ни одного прилагательного.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это  д/з

Comment: просто не найду ни одного прилагательного

Comment: Тогда переформулируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы: здесь нет прилагательных.